# Formatting lollipop graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have the following code and subsequent graph.  How do I:

1) make my the PY axis include all the PYs (i.e include 2009, 2011,2013, 2015, and 2017)

2) go in ascending order (i.e. 2009 on top and 2018 on bottom

3) change the scale of my Perc axis, maybe to go by .2 instead of .25 and maybe add more gridlines

data:

[image]

`structure(list(PY = structure(c(1230768000, 1262304000, 1293840000, 
    1325376000, 1356998400, 1388534400, 1420070400, 1451606400, 1483228800, 
    1514764800, 1546300800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Perc = c(0.197, 0.266, 0.2, 0.3, 0.397, 0.553, 0.57, 0.621, 
    0.556, 0.6, 0.293)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))`

code:

```
ggplot(Ult_sum, aes(x=PY, y=Perc)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=PY, xend=PY, y=0, yend=1.0), color="skyblue") +
  geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
#  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
     panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()    
  )
```

graph:

[image]

As a bonus, I also get the below warning/error:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

which seems to remove my PY 2019 for no apparent reason.  thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question to include data needed to reproduce your problem - use `dput(Ult_sum)` to put the data into an easily imported format

Comment: added a view of my data.  Let me know if that's sufficient.

Comment: I think i did it!  (sorry i'm new at this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First plot replicates the code given in the question. Second plot is the adjusted plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(stringr)

# data
Ult_sum <- structure(list(PY = structure(c(1230768000, 1262304000, 1293840000, 
                                1325376000, 1356998400, 1388534400, 1420070400, 1451606400, 1483228800, 
                                1514764800, 1546300800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               Perc = c(0.197, 0.266, 0.2, 0.3, 0.397, 0.553, 0.57, 0.621, 
                        0.556, 0.6, 0.293)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))
# code given
ggplot(Ult_sum, aes(x=PY, y=Perc)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=PY, xend=PY, y=0, yend=1.0), color="skyblue") +
  geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  #  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()    
  )
```

[image]

```r
# Adjust plot
Ult_sum <- Ult_sum %>% 
   mutate(PY = as.Date(PY),
          PY = factor(PY),
          PY = fct_rev(PY))

ggplot(Ult_sum, aes(x=PY, y=Perc)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=PY, xend=PY, y=0, yend=1.0), color="skyblue") +
  geom_point(color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_extract(x, "^\\d{4}")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .2), minor_breaks = seq(0, 1, .05)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()    
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: your use data.frame throws me 'cuz you format how you want.  this works but removes '19:

`Ult_sum

PYa<- factor(Ult_sum$PY)


ggplot(Ult_sum, aes(x=fct_rev(PYa), y=Perc)) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=fct_rev(PYa), xend=fct_rev(PYa), y=0, yend=1.0), color="skyblue") +
  geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .2), minor_breaks = seq(0, 1, .05))+
  #  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
     panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()    
  )`

Comment: Hm. I think there is a problem with the value for year 2019 or the value for the date itself. That's for sure the reason why you get warnings, which mean nothing less then R dropped one raw because of a missing. But from the picture of your data I can't figure out what the problem is. First check your data. Second. Set it up manually. Third. Put your dataset in your question as Richard mentioned in his comment.

Comment: I added data the way @RichardTelford mentioned.  was that correct?

Comment: Yep. Fine. I check it out.

Comment: Hi. Just edited the code and put your data inside. However. Your data looks fine. Got no warnings. Also checked your code. As you can see from the first picture. At least on my machine the year 2019 shows up with your code.